# Expandablelistview's background becomes whiter when I expand child row

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Expandablelistview's background becomes whiter when I expand child rows. How can I fix it?

I set:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@null"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

I also tried:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

But it doesn't fix the problem.

Screenshot before expanding child:

http://i.imgur.com/fbaKPus.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywz9M.png

after:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xyxx.png

EDIT:

Application uses Sherlock theme:
    
    ...

Expandablelistview xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:childDivider="@color/expandablelist_divider"
        android:divider="@color/expandablelist_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandablelistindicator" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the first screenshot is not found

Comment: Have you tried with android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" only? without android:scrollingCache="false"

Comment: have you set a specific theme to your application?

Comment: @Nickolaus - yes, I'm using Sherlock theme: android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: could you post all the xml file? are your ExpandableListView inheriting some style? in that case, try to build one new that inherit of that, add the new atributes and assign to your ExpandableListView.

Comment: @FernandoValle - I edited my post and added xml file. What attributes should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theming is causing your problem, one way would be create custom selectors or, I recommend using the Android Holo Colors Generator and maybe also the Android Action Bar Style Generator from this [site](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html), which creates a harmonic design.

Comment: What files/attributes should I replace? I tried custom Action Bar style but it doesn't solve the problem. Maybe I can modify Action Bar Sherlock's source?

Comment: there is no need just place the resources from the archive into your project, then you can refer to the style made by the generator tool